# Making qemu look better

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu

I have a machine running kubuntu, and use qemu to run a VM. It looks really bad as you can see in the screenshot. What can I do to make it better?

- I prefer solutions that don't require sudo access, because this is a university computer and I have to ask the sysadmin to do the changes for me.

[image]

That wired noisy box, is actually a terminal window.

Comment: Exactly which screenshot are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it.